# How can I give players items that are automatically equipped In Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I give someone maybe a chest plate and it will automatically equip them with it?

Comment: Again, have you looked online for answers? Our site runs differently than others, and we'd always prefer if you tried to help yourself before asking.

Comment: What should happen if the player already has a chestplate equipped?

Comment: Yes, I searched for answers and I have a different command block clear their inventory before equipping items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command to specify with slot to place an item:

```
/replaceitem entity @a armor.chest minecraft:iron_chestplate{}
```

And you can do this for the helmet etc.

If you'd like to equip the player with a sword you could do:

```
/replaceitem entity @a weapon.mainhand minecraft:iron_sword{}
```

To equip the player with a sword in their hand, i.e. the slot of the Hotbar they are currently using. The same for a shield with:

```
/replaceitem entity @a weapon.offhand minecraft:shield{}
```

**Important Note**

`/replaceitem` will be replaced with `/item` in 1.17, but you can easily convert to the new command.

Instead of this:

```
/replaceitem entity @a armor.chest minecraft:iron_chestplate{}
```

It should be like this:

```
/replaceitem entity @a armor.chest replace minecraft:iron_chestplate{}
```